# Venv and Memory Usage, Should I be Concerned?

Tags: python-venv

I'm fairly new to using venv's. With the many different packages is there a way to tell how much each venv is using? When I delete a venv am I also removing the memory space allocated for everything located within?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> When I delete a venv am I also removing the memory space allocated for everything located within?

Yes.

---

`virtualenv` will produce a separate "*Virtual Environment*" that can be used independently from the system's Python environment. This allows you to do useful things, like install packages without root access and change the default python interpreter's version.

As you know, it's easy to set up:

```
$ virtualenv -p python3.5 ./venv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.5
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/attie/venv/bin/python3.5
Also creating executable in /home/attie/venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
```

Having done this, you will find the whole virtual environment within the `venv` directory... and it's simple to inspect how much storage it's using - 18MB in my case:

```
$ du -hs venv
18M     venv
```

After activating the environment, you'll see that the `pip` / `python` / etc... binaries are located in your `venv` directory:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ . venv/bin/activate
$ which python
/home/attie/venv/bin/python
```

It's completely self-contained - running `pip install` will affect this virtual environment, and won't alter the wider system installation at all.

When you decide that "*I don't want that anymore*", or "*oops, I broke something, let's start again*", you can simply remove and reinitialize the virtual environment (if you want).

Deleting this directory will free up all storage used by that virtual environment:

```
$ rm -rf venv
```

---

If you place your project files inside the virtual environment's directory (i.e: `venv` in this example), then you will also loose your project files. This is *not* recommended.

If you instead keep your project's files outside the virtual environment (recommended), then deleting the `venv` directory will not tidy up your project files too - as you would expect.

---

It's worth noting a couple of things:

- A virtual environment can be deactivated by running `deactivate`. Activating the virtual environment will alter the shell's environment, so if you have activated the environment in this shell, then you should deactivate it before deleting it.
- Virtual environments don't like being moved, **at all** - they'll break completely. Instead, you'll need to delete (if you want) and setup a new virtual environment in the new location.

Comment: This is great, Attie. Thank you!